# Changing the culling mode in the HLSL effect

Tags: hlsl, directx11, slimdx, culling, effect

I'm writing a cel-shading effect in HLSL and Direct3D 11, and I need to be able to flip the culling mode on the outline pass of the effect.  I know you do this in XNA by setting **CullMode** to **CW** or **CCW** inside the pass definition, but is that how you do it in D3D11/SlimDX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by creating rasterizer state and setting it active in context. See [D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SlimDX.Direct3D11.RasterizerStateDescription.IsFrontCounterclockwise](http://slimdx.org/docs/#P_SlimDX_Direct3D11_RasterizerStateDescription_IsFrontCounterclockwise).

And if you use Effect11 framework, then you can do that directly in fx file like this:

```
// define your rasterizer state
RasterizerState MyCull {
    FrontCounterClockwise = TRUE; // or FALSE
};

// in some effect pass use MyCull state for Rasterizer State
SetRasterizerState( MyCull );
```